# Does $f(0) = 0 \implies f'(x) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Assuming $f(x)$ is differentiable $\forall x$

In my textbook, for one of the questions, it says

$f(0) = f'(0) = 0$, I was a little confused since I

thought $f(0) = 0 \implies f'(x) = 0$ and thought it was

redundant, but I'm probably wrong. If I am, can someone

perhaps give a counterexample?

Comment: indeed. Because 0 is differentiable.

Comment: Does $f(x)=0 \forall x$ or are you meaning at a specific point $x$?

Comment: @IanMiller sorry I made a typo I meant to say $f(0) = 0$ rather than $f(x) = 0$

Comment: Whats the question in the book where it says $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. Some context will help us answer your problem.

Comment: Okay, with the new edit, no, it is possible for $f(0)=0$ but $f'(0)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=x$ then $f(0)=0$ but $f'(x)=1$ so not true for all cases.

Comment: According to your edit yes as 0 is constant

Comment: I think he mean that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Yes so i wrote my comment

Answer (score 0):

Saying $f(x)=0$ can mean different things depending on context. If the function being defined, then it means that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, in which case your reasoning is correct. Sometimes, though, it means that for a particular $x$, $f(x)$ takes the value of zero, in which case $f'(x)$ also being zero is notable.

Your recent edit indicates that $f(x)$ equals zero when $x=0$, but not necessarily all $x$. In this case, as in $f(x)=x$, $f(0)=0$, but $f'(x)$ may not be zero.